# invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError) when using arrow keys in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, utf-8

When using the arrow keys in my rails console inside my docker container the following error happens, and afterwards the console shuts down.

It isn't related to my .irb_history containing odd characters as I don't have one, and it happens even with the left/right arrow keys.

```
irb(main):001:0> /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4269:in `block in _rl_dispatch_subseq': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4269:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4269:in `detect'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4269:in `_rl_dispatch_subseq'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4271:in `_rl_dispatch_subseq'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4251:in `_rl_dispatch'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4669:in `readline_internal_charloop'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4743:in `readline_internal'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/rbreadline.rb:4765:in `readline'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rb-readline-0.4.2/lib/readline.rb:40:in `readline'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/input-method.rb:151:in `gets'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:473:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:627:in `signal_status'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:472:in `block in eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:189:in `buf_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:104:in `getc'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/slex.rb:206:in `match_io'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/slex.rb:76:in `match'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:283:in `token'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:265:in `lex'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:236:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `loop'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:489:in `eval_input'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:430:in `block in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:429:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:429:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb.rb:385:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I tried using another terminal (zsh), running ruby 2.6.6, as well as setting the following ENVS with no success.

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Where else could I be looking at?

Comment: Upgrade `rb-readline` gem from `0.4.2` to `0.5` and your issue will be solved.

Comment: Next time I will first make sure that the gem raising an error isn't present in my Gemfile rather than assuming it is a system gem. Thank you!